# puppetdb no route to host when installing with PuppetDB module

Tags: puppet

Trying to install PuppetDB on a separate node using PuppetDB (v5.1.2) module and I'm getting 
`Notice: Unable to connect to puppetdb server (https://puppetdb.example.com:8081): Connection refused - connect(2) for "puppetdb.example.com" port 8081` when running Puppet agent on Puppet Server (trying to configure the server with PuppetDB module).
Here's my **site.pp**

```
node 'puppetserver.example.com' {

  class { 'puppetdb::master::config':
    puppetdb_server => 'puppetdb.example.com',
  }
}
node 'puppetdb.example.com' {

  class { 'puppetdb::database::postgresql':
    listen_addresses => '0.0.0.0',
  }

  class { 'puppetdb::server':
    database_host => 'puppetdb.example.com',
  }
}
```

PuppetDB is running, in `jetty.ini` `host` and `ssl-host` is set to `0.0.0.0`. Ssl certificates are okay.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What node is failing to connect to the PuppetDB?

Comment: Node with Puppet Server.

Comment: Yes, theoretically you can use any port, but they seem to have stuff hardcoded to use port 8081.

Comment: Netstat shows PuppetDB is listening the port although I can't telnet it.
`tcp6       0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN      5960/java`

Comment: In your master config, are you using the puppetDB hostname or IP? If the hostname is been used, can your master resolve it? On your master, check if the puppetDB port is open, with netcat or even telnet.

Comment: The problem was in iptables running on PuppetDB. The strange thing is I was using the same vagrant box for both Server and DB. On Puppet Server VM there's no iptables at all, only firewalld.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please verify the following config files too

```
    /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppetdb.conf
   [main]
   server_urls = https://puppetdb.example.com:8081
```

And

```
    /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/routes.yaml
   ---
   master:
   facts:
      terminus: puppetdb
      cache: yaml
```

These files should have been populated by your puppetdb and should have the exact entry as above.

Another important config is your ssl setup for puppetdb ,verify it using below command .

```
puppetdb ssl-setup
```